# Magento 2 - Brexit VAT rules for Children's clothing store

Tags: magento, shopify, e-commerce, magento2, checkout

My store sells children's clothing that should be 0% VAT as per new Brexit regulations, but it's not limited to this, some products we sell are miscellaneous, like sunglasses and bags that are 20% VAT. Due to Brexit we will have to do some changes to our product taxation.

The changes after 31st of December are:

A cart that is >135 pounds will always be sold with 0% tax (this is easy to implement, just add a checkout/cart rule that if the cart is >135, then tax = 0%)

A cart that is <135 pounds has to be sold with 20% tax (this is the one I need assistance with)

The issue is, I'm not sure what is the most logical way of implementing this, for example if a customer adds some products that are 0% and some that are 20% VAT, and the cart is <135 pounds, does taxation apply to all of the cart, ignoring the 0%?

How are you dealing with this? Any suggestions or resolutions are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: This question is better answered by Shopify support team and /or in Shopify forums.

Comment: @HymnZzy this has nothing to do with Shopify - read the question

Answer (score 1):

For orders > £135
You say its easy to implement. There is no option to set Tax @ 0% in cart rules. You can only offer a percentage discount, so Tax is applied but you get a discount. However the discount percentage is only on the products. Not the delivery! and delivery to EU just got more expensive...
Maybe I'm missing something
for orders < £135
You can create additional "Product Tax Class" in the Tax Rules section. If you have more than 1 Product tax class, you get an option to select it on each product individually (which you can do by import/export in bulk). So create a 0% and a 20% one and apply them to each product as you wish.

I think the first bit is actually the tricky bit. I have no idea how to do that one.